# How to make 5* 8 collection view in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I want to create a UICollectionView with 5*8 matrix everytime. (means 5 rows and 8 columns)for all iphone screens. 
And Collectionview constraints are :

Leading to superview = 10

Trailing to superview = 10

Top to superview = 90

Bottom to superview = 150

Collection view result should show like :

[image]
Result View

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NavigateCollectionViewCell

        cell.questionLbl.text = items[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }
```

Please help out with this.

Comment: self.view.frame.size.width(with space) / 5

Comment: And what did you try? It sounds like you've just put up your specification and you expect someone to provide the code for you.

Comment: And if you are going to post code, try and make it relevant to the question. The methods to get a cell and to handle selections has nothing to do with the layout of the cells in the Collection View which is what your question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the desire out put with

```
let cellWidth : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.width - 20.0 - (5 * YOUR_CELLSPACING)) / 5.0
let cellHeight : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.height - 260.0 - (8 * LINE_Spacing)) / 8.0
let collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = (self.YOUR_COLLECTIONVIEW!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout)

collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth , height:cellHeight)
```

This may result in different height and view.

If you want to keep you height and width same then you just simply do

//UICollectioncell with respect to width like

```
collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth , height:cellWidth)
```

//Height

//UICollectioncell with respect to width like

```
collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellHeight , height:cellHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your collectionView delegates

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20) / 5
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth);
    }
```

Instead of 20, you can give the total leading + trailing values from the margin + inter cell spacing.